# How to select 2 post pages in wordpress website

Tags: wordpress

I have created a website using wordpress.

I have 2 main menu:- 1. travel
2. sketches

How i configure that my travel post is shows in travel menu and my sketch post shows in sketch menu.

Comment: Appearance --> Menus --> Manage Locations?

Comment: Sir, Travel menu is post page, when i create a post related sketches then it shows in travel menu but i want sketch post shows in sketch menu. How i setup that things

Comment: Maybe you can add an image that will illustrate the problem? Either way you can manually remove pages from menus and manually add them to other.